# second derived subgroup for the group on two generators $a,b$ with $[a,b]=a$

Tags: group-theory

Reading one of the articles of Higman, I encountered the following reasoning obvious to the author:

***Let $G=\langle a,b\mid [a,b]=a\rangle$. Then the second derived subgroup of $G$ is trivial.***

I tried to prove it using commutator identities $$[xy,z]=[x,z]^y[y,z],\quad\quad [x,yz]=[x,z][x,y]^z$$ with the notation $x^y=y^{-1}xy$, $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, but somehow I couldn't make ends meet. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the relation $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=a$ as $b^{-1}ab=a^2$. (The group is actually the Baumslag-Solitar group ${\rm BS}(1,2)$.)

Let $a_n=b^{-n}ab^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (so $a_0=a)$. So $b^{-1}a_nb=a_{n+1}$. Note also that, for all $n \in {\mathbb Z}$,
$$a_{n+1} = b^{-n}b^{-1}abb^n = b^{-n}a^2b^n = (b^{-n}ab^n)^2 = a_n^2,$$
 so the subgroup $N$ of $G$ generated by the $a_n$ is abelian. Now, since $b^{-1}a_nb=a_{n+1}$ for all $n$, $N$ is normalized by $b$ and centralized by $a$, so it is normal in $G$, and $G/N = \langle bN \rangle$ is infinite cyclic. Hence $N$ and $G/N$ are both abelian, so the second derived group of $G$ is trivial.

Comment: Why is it normalised by $b$? How do you get $b^{-1}a^{-1}b=a^i$? (I can do it using commutator identities, because $[b, a^{-1}]=[a, b]^{a^{-1}}=a$...but this doesn't come under "clearly". Am I missing something?)

Comment: It is normalized by $b$ because $b^{-1}a_nb=a_{n+1}$. And $[a,b]=a \Rightarrow a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=a \Rightarrow b^{-1}ab=a^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you, this totally makes sense!

Comment: Like many things, it's not hard if you have seen it before, but if not then it is not at all obvious how to proceed.